# Why does auto works differently in "range for" in 2D and 1D arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, pointers, auto

Hi I am working with 2D and 1D arrays in C++ and using *range for* to access elements.The code that i am using is as follows:

**For 2D Arrays**

```
int ia[3][4] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
for (auto& row : ia) {
    for (auto col : row) {
        cout << col << endl;
    }
}
```

**For ID Array**

```
int base_array[2] = { 1, 2 };
for (auto p : base_array) {
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
}
```

So as we can see in the outside range for loop of 2D array, the control variable **row** must be of reference type so that the automatic array to pointer conversion does not happen and we can loop through the elements which themselves are arrays of size 4. But in the 1D array we are not using the control variable **p** as a reference type and even then we are able to traverse through the 1D array. My question is **why in the 1D array the array to pointer conversion is not taking place**? How is it working without the control variable being of reference type? That is, why (how) is `p` of `int` type instead of `int*` in 1D array case while if we omit the reference symbol in the control variable **row** it will then become a int* but when we include the reference symbol in front of variable **row** then it will become an array type. Why there is this difference in behavior?

Comment: Range-based for isn't magically different. You're just not understanding your types correctly.

Comment: @sweenish I am understanding the types correctly. I have checked the code many times now and all the types i have checked before posting this question. The variable p is of type int instead of int* and the variable row(without the reference type) is of type pointer to array but with a reference symbol it is of type array.

Comment: how you think `for (auto& row : ia)` works? it's also 1D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case** 1(*Without reference symbol infront of row*)

For the outside loop, the loop variable `row` is initialized to the first element of `ia` which is itself an array and since we're not using reference here, so the array to pointer conversion will take place and `row` will become `int*`. And since we cannot loop through an `int*`, we get an error when we try to do so in the inner for loop.

**Case** 2(*With reference symbol infront of row*)

When we add reference symbol infont of `row`, then `row` will be deduced as `int(&)[4]`, meaning a reference to an array of size `4` with elements of type `int`. And since we can loop through this, the inner loop works here.

Answer (score 5):

In your 1D case, base_array isn't decayed because it exists in the same scope as the for loop. So the range-based for can correctly figure out its range. That's really it, the 1D isn't decayed. If you had tried passing that 1D array through a function, you'd see that the range-based for becomes impossible because it will decay, unless you passed it as a reference.

In your 2D case, if you allow `row` to decay to `int*`, the nested for can no longer assume you must mean an array. So, you preserve the type by using `auto&`, allowing the nested for to know what you're talking about.

Comment: The same reasons apply. Like I initially commented, you're not understanding the types correctly. The types and the "why" are explained in all the answers here. You need to be clearer about what specifically you're not understanding.

Comment: It sounds like you've repeated my answer in your own words, which is a good sign that you understand it (seriously, restating a problem in your own words is a key problem solving technique). So to answer your questions, yes and yes.

Answer (score 3):

> why in the 1D array the array to pointer conversion is not taking place?

In the case of 1D array, the elements of the array are `int` objects whereas in the case of 2D array, the elements of the array are "array of `int`" objects.

Without using a reference, an array of `int` will decay to a pointer. Hence, it is appropriate to use a reference for the first case.

Answer (score 0):

From the C++ 17 Standard (10.1.7.4.1 Placeholder type deduction)

> 4 If the placeholder is the auto type-specifier, the deduced type T0
> replacing T is determined using the rules for template argument
> deduction. Obtain P from T by replacing the occurrences of auto with
> either a new invented type template parameter U or, if the
> initialization is copy-list-initialization, with
> std::initializer_list. **Deduce a value for U using the rules of template argument
> deduction from a function call (17.8.2.1)**

and (17.8.2.1 Deducing template arguments from a function call)

> 2 If P is not a reference type:
>
> (2.1) — If A is an array type, the pointer type produced by the
> array-to-pointer standard conversion (7.2) is used in place of A for
> type deduction; otherwise,

Thus if you will not use a referenced type in the loop

```
for (auto row : ia)
```

then the type of the variable row will be `int *` that is it will be a pointer type for which you can not use the range based for loop.

Comment: @JasonLiam In the range based for loop for 1D array the deduced type of the declared variable is a scalar type that is outputted. For 2D array you need at first get a reference to 1D array that is the element of the 2D array that again to use the range-based for loop for an array.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ok i understand what is going on now(without reference symbol). In the outside loop variable row is initialized to the first element of ia which is iteself an array, so array to pointer conversion will take place and row will become int*. And therefore we cannot loop through the int* . Is this correct? And if yes, then does this mean that when we add reference symbol infont of row, then that array to pointer conversion will no longer take place and row will remain an array.Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow For the last sentence, was it `int(*)[4]` or `int(*)`? I think it would be the latter by some compiler messages, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Eric  Its type will be int *. That is iterators for the two-dimensional array have the type int ( * )[4]. Dereferencing them you will get references int ( & )[4] that are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements of the type int *.